# Restricting to iOS devices with A8 or better GPU

Tags: ios, opengl-es, device, require, info.plist

I need to restrict my app to only support devices with A8 or newer GPUs.

In my `info.plist` I have the key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` set to `opengles-3`:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
    <string>opengles-3</string>
</array>
```

But this means that it supports A7 GPUs or newer. I have looked at all the keys and I don't see anyway to restrict A7 devices, but it seems like there most be a way since A8 GPUs are considerably more capable than the A7s. The require `metal` key supports the same devices that are OpenGL ES 3 capable. Requiring `arm64` will not work either since the iPhone 5s has an A7 GPU.

Can anyone recommend a way to support only A8 or better?

Comment: If there's not an exposed key it's likely trying to find a restriction to just A8 outside the standard keys would lead to your app being rejected by Apple on submission.

Comment: I'm not looking for hidden or undocumented solutions, but I can't believe that an app that supports A10 GPUs is required to support A7 GPUs. The A10 renders over 400% faster performance compared to the A7.

Comment: It definitely feels weird, but fits the Apple model of "as long support as possible, no matter how much it sucks (for devs)"

Comment: I thought they usually advocated for not supporting older devices to sell reasons to upgrade. It honestly doesn't suck for me as much as it will suck for consumers running A7 devices, and I really wanted to offer a consistent user experience across supported devices and I apparently can't.

Answer (score 0):

You should be eliminating it only by using plist in order not to get rejected

Here is the [compatibility reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) unfortunately i cannot see any thing that can eliminate iPhone 5S.

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned I looked at all of those keys and I don't see any way to limit A7 devices in them, so I don't know why you think this is the answer?

Comment: I think yes it's the answer :(

Comment: How does it _answer_ the question of requiring A8 or better GPUs?

Comment: I meant you cannot using the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities and since you should not restrict devices with any other way you cannot eliminate iPhone5s from this

Comment: That was already mentioned as part of the question. I asked the question because it could be possible that there is another way to restrict devices, or something that I hadn't thought of.